# What was Skynet's "defense grid"?

Tags: the-terminator-series, skynet

According to Kyle Reese,

> "Skynet's defense grid was smashed; we won"

That seems an odd phrase to use. Has the defense grid been explained in expanded universe materials? Was it a  big switch to turn the Terminators off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It explains in the novelisation of the first (or maybe second) film that the "defence grid" was literally a fortification around it's headquarters.  Breaching it was like breaking through the wall of a castle's keep in medieval times, Skynet had nowhere else to hide or command from.

This is what Kyle was referring to.  The defence grid (aka defence perimeter) was smashed and Skynet's last fortress was conquered - the war was over in that time.

The resistance smashed through the grid and through the compounds and got to the time displacement equipment just as it sent the Terminators back.  They quickly sent Kyle though after the first Terminator and reprogrammed another Terminator, gave it as much information as they could from memory about the T1000 and sent it back.  Then the blew the place up.  That was it - the war was won but (as explained in the prologue of the first film) the final battle was not fought there, it was fought [here], [tonight].

Answer (score 3):

That's been a different Skynet from the one from the other movies. It had a central location where it's computer core, memory, etc. have been located. The story was written pre-internet/cloud computing.

When he refers to "defense grid" we're talking about physical things such as turrets, robots, missile batteries, etc. - whatever they initially installed to protect Skynet or whatever Skynet added on its own. Essentially things such as the tanks and aircraft we see during the few futuristic scenes in the first two movies.

In short, humankind had won the war, Skynet lost. They reached Skynet and were short before eliminating it (i.e. the defenses have been breached). The story of the first movie is essentially the story of Skynet's last attempt to still turn the tides and win the war by killing John Connor (or more specifically Sarah), to avoid humankind having that one leader who finally manages to unite most survivors who'll eventually take out Skynet.

If you've seen *2001: A Space Odyssey*, which you probably have, imagine a similar situation for Terminator. A rampant AI is to be shut down, so you'll have to get to one central point to turn it off or "kill" it. Just that in this case there are weapons and stuff in place to keep "Dave" from doing such weird things.